# How do I auto-start a program for a specific user using the CurrentVersion\Run key in the registry?

Tags: c++, windows, registry, 64-bit, autostart

I have a 32-bit application that writes to:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

my application path so that it will be started when the current user logs on. This works fine on 32-bit systems (i.e. the application auto-starts).

I understand that on 64-bit systems, registry redirection comes into play. So, I searched for:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

but the CurrentVersion sub-key does not exist (the Wow6432Node key exists though)! So, I manually created it and my application wrote correctly to the registry (I went into the registry and checked. The entry was there). BUT, the application did not auto-start when the current user logged in. Can someone tell me why?

Btw, all this is fine if I use the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE branch. But, I want this to be user-specific.

#### Why am I not just using the Startup folder?

When UAC is enabled and set to always notify, this simply does not work (i.e. my application does not auto-start). And no, I cannot disable UAC. I require that my application play nice with UAC enabled and set to always notify.

If someone can tell me why, I will gladly forget my need to use the registry (I hate the registry).

#### Fallback option (last resort):

I will use the Task Scheduler APIs to do this. But, I will do this only when there is **absolutely no other way**.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're running anti-virus software it may be preventing your application from modifying `\CurrentVersion\Run` in the registry.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I checked the registry after closing the application. The expected entry was at the expected place.

Comment: Might want to open up the Event Viewer (in Admin tools) and see if Windows reports an error during startup. If there's something wrong with your registry entry or launching the app in general there's a good change you will see an entry in the event viewer

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I checked the System and Application logs just now. No errors/information about the application in question.

Comment: What happens when you write to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` in a 64-bit OS?  Does the registry key exist and it is not being launched or is the registry key not written?

Comment: @Steve, My application actually checks whether the OS is a 64-bit one. If it is, I pass the [`KEY_WOW64_32KEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx) flag to all registry functions.

Comment: @AnishRam If you manually write the registry key into `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (no wow6432node) is the application launched?

Comment: @Steve, Nope. I tried that first. That case alone exhibits the same behaviour as when I try the Startup folder method (i.e. application doesn't auto-start).

Comment: @AnishRam I think you have some other issue, but I don't know what.  I've just created an autoruns key to run a 32-bit application and it worked fine.  Created string value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` called `calc` with data `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\calc.exe`.  If you have the same problem with your app being in the startup folder then it's not a registry 32/64 bit virtualization problem.

Comment: @Steve, Did you also enable UAC and set it to always notify?

Comment: Does the program require elevation?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I think so. It has a self-update feature which replaces certain binaries. So if the program is installed in C:\Program Files, wouldn't it need elevation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to launch an executable requiring elevation from the user's Run key or from the Startup folder.  See [Elevations Are Now Blocked in the User's Logon Path](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uac/archive/2006/08/23/715265.aspx) from the UAC team's blog.

The best solution is probably to configure the executable to not require elevation.  It can then launch an elevated copy of itself only if and when actually needed.  Or you could use a service for the tasks that require elevation, this is the only good approach if you need to be able to perform elevated tasks on behalf of users who do not have administrator privilege.

Another option, since you can successfully launch the process using HKLM, would be to have it launch for all users but exit immediately if it isn't the user(s) you want.

Answer (score 1):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is shared between 32-bit and 64-bit applications (there is no redirection and Wow6432Node key). Here is the list with [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hmm. I was originally of this impression. I tried this, but no cigar.